# force specific shell environment variable on process using /etc/pam.d/ rules

Tags: shell, pam, passwd, slim

I am using slim login manager, and it has its own pam rules file: `/etc/pam.d/slim`.

```
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-auth
@include common-account

session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so

@include common-session
@include common-password
```

it seems that the `pam_env.so` rules are setting the environment variables for the running process, such as: `USER`, `HOME`, `PWD`, `SHELL`, ...

Is it possible, after these have been set, to force `SHELL` to be `/bin/sh`?
I mean, regardless what shell user has specified in `/etc/passwd`, I want to force to use `/bin/sh` for slim process.